# Running Windows batch files from Emacs

Tags: windows, batch-file, emacs, cmd

I'm somewhat new to gnu emacs, and so perhaps this is a noob question, but I have a few batch files I use a lot when coding in emacs to compile/build/execute/debug/etc. I am wondering how I could A) run these batch files from emacs without having to keep opening a cmd prompt window or going to windows explorer and B) bind this to a key shortcut (perhaps I could specify the file?) I have seen several things online about running emacs in batch-mode, but I don't believe this is what I'm looking for. And I know it is possible because I have seen others run batch from emacs (output and everything would appear in a new buffer adjacent to the current as if you did `C-x 3`)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To run an arbitrary shell command in Emacs, you call `shell-command` which is bound to <kbd>M-!</kbd>

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `shell-command` (or <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>M-!</kbd>) for details.

I believe in the Windows-native Emacs, the default shell is `cmd` (or some alias thereof), so I'm reasonably confident that this is what you're thinking of.

I'm not sure whether all of the following work in Windows, but related commands are:

- <kbd>M-&</kbd> - `async-shell-command`
- <kbd>M-|</kbd> - `shell-command-on-region`

And with a prefix argument (e.g. <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-!</kbd>) any of those commands will insert the shell command's output into the *current* buffer. (In the case of `shell-command-on-region`, that *replaces* the region.)

Comment: When I try this, it tells me it can't run the cmd.exe. Also I'm not 100% sure if this is what I'm looking for. Correct me if wrong, but the suggestions you give only apply to running a single shell command, where as I want to execute an entire batch file

Comment: A "shell command" is anything that you could enter from a shell prompt. If the shell is `cmd`, then a "shell command" is anything you could execute from a `cmd` prompt. I assume your batch file is executable, and that you would run it by specifying its name or path as the shell command to run.

Comment: I understand that, but when I tried it, all I get in return is a message saying the system32/cmd.exe can't be run

Comment: I can't help with that one, other than to tell you that `shell-command` uses the value of the `shell-file-name` variable as the shell to pass the command to. Whenever I've used Windows I've always integrated Emacs with Cygwin's bash shell, though, so I'm not familiar with problems using the Windows shell (although on the occasions that Cygwin wasn't set up, my recollection is that `cmd` was being used correctly by default, as you'd expect).